Why using a variable instead of a string in XPath expression doesn't return the results
Consider
an "Execute Xpath expression" action in Power Automate Desktop:
//component//element[text()=${InputDialogTextVariable}]/ancestor::component/@category

That is reading an XML file with a following structure:
<root>
    <components>
        <component category="Category 1">
            <elements>
                <element>VAL00001</element>
                <element>VAL00002</element>
                <element>VAL00003</element>
            </elements>
        </component>
        <component category="Category 2">
            <elements>
                <element>VAL00011</element>
                <element>VAL00012</element>
                <element>VAL00013</element>
            </elements>
        </component>
    </components>
</root>

This, unfortunately, returns an empty list of results.
${InputDialogTextVariable} holds the user input and therefore needs to be a variable.
If I "hard-code" the string like this:
//component//element[text()='VAL00001']/ancestor::component/@category

Then it will return Category 1 as the only item in the list of results.
I tried
converting ${InputDialogTextVariable} into string like this:
//component//element[text()=string(${InputDialogTextVariable})]/ancestor::component/@category

Earlier I was using contains() method to find my element but it was returning category values that shouldn't be a match.
Searching for "VAL00001" would return both "Category 1" and "Category 2" values as if "VAL00011" is also a match.
Why is this even a problem. Any insight?

Does element[text()='${InputDialogTextVariable}'] work in your environment?

Or try element[.='%InputDialogTextVariable%'].

I would suggest looking at the XPath string constructed when the variable is expanded - it should be fairly obvious what's wrong. Probably missing quotes.

@MartinHonnen element[text()='${InputDialogTextVariable}'] did the trick. I thought I tried single and double quotes but apparently not in this way. I've investigated the expanded variable and it was missing the quotes, so I tried putting them around the variable. Thank you for your help!
